# Why User Name can not start with special character

Tags: validation, authentication, user-input

I have a doubt about validating user LogIn.why User name can not be start with special character is there any technical reason or its just due to naming convention only.Can any one clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

It is your system.  If you want to allow special characters in user names, then do it.

Comment: that is ok,but it is a part of validation